# Apply Sequential Labels To Records in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm sure this is simple enough to do but I can't seem to frame the question right in Google. I have order data from an ecommerce store, I want to be able to do a select query to label a customer's 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc orders (based on date) so I can map out other metrics downstream.

**Example Source Data:**

| customer id | order # | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc1 | 3/1/22 |
| 187 | abc2 | 3/3/22 |
| 123 | abc3 | 3/17/22 |
| 165 | abc4 | 3/19/22 |
| 123 | abc5 | 3/22/22 |

**Desired Result:**

| customer id | order # | date | Order Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc1 | 3/1/22 | First Order |
| 187 | abc2 | 3/3/22 | First Order |
| 123 | abc3 | 3/17/22 | Second Order |
| 165 | abc4 | 3/19/22 | First Order |
| 123 | abc5 | 3/22/22 | Third Order |

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return the *numeric* sequence:

```vb
Select 
    [customer id],
    [order #],
    [date],
        (Select Count(*) 
        From YourTable As T 
        Where T.[customer id] = YourTable.[customer id] 
        And T.[date] <= YourTable.[date]) As [Order Sequence No.]
From
    YourTable
Order By
    [date],
    [customer id]
```

You can browse for a lot of solutions to spell out the numbers to English.